# Atomic max for floats in OpenCL

Tags: max, opencl, atomic

I need an atomic max function for floats in OpenCL. This is my current naive code using atomic_xchg

```
float value = data[index];
if ( value  > *max_value )
{
    atomic_xchg(max_value, value);
}
```

This code gives the correct result when using an Intel CPU, but not for a Nvidia GPU. Is this code correct, or can anyone help me?

Comment: Looks like others have fought this problem. For example: https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/408491/atomicmax-with-floats/

Comment: cuda documentation explains how to implement atomic functions for float/double using compare-swap http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions same can be done on opencl

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
 //Function to perform the atomic max
 inline void AtomicMax(volatile __global float *source, const float operand) {
    union {
        unsigned int intVal;
        float floatVal;
    } newVal;
    union {
        unsigned int intVal;
        float floatVal;
    } prevVal;
    do {
        prevVal.floatVal = *source;
        newVal.floatVal = max(prevVal.floatVal,operand);
    } while (atomic_cmpxchg((volatile __global unsigned int *)source, prevVal.intVal, newVal.intVal) != prevVal.intVal);
}

__kernel mykern(__global float *data, __global float *max_value){
    unsigned int index = get_global_id(0);

    float value = data[index];
    AtomicMax(max_value, value);
}
```

As stated in [LINK](http://suhorukov.blogspot.co.uk/2011/12/opencl-11-atomic-operations-on-floating.html).

What it does is create a union of float and int. Perform the math on the float, but compare integers when doing the atomic xchg. As long as the integers match, the operation is completed.

However, the speed decrease due to the use of these methods is very high. Use them carefully.

Comment: How does this handle integers corresponding to a float NaN?

Comment: A NaN is defined as `s111 1111 1axx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx xxxx` where `s` is the sign (-NaN, NaN) often ignored, and `a` indicates if it is a quiet NaN. So, after all, a NaN is an valid integer number and will work exactly as good.

However, as defined by OpenCL. The `max()` operation will ignore any NaN value inputted, and get only the maximum valid value.

The upper code will work exactly as good with NaNs (following the Spec).