# OpenCL : Id of the physical core being used

Tags: opencl

I'm trying to get something to work but I run out of ideas so I figured I would ask here.

I have a kernel that has a large global size (usually 5 Million)
Each of the threads can require up to 1Mb of global memory (exact size not known in advance)

So i figured... ok, on my typical target GPU I have 6Gb and I can run 2880 threads in parrallel, more than enough right ?
My idea is to create a big buffer (well actually 2 because of the max buffer size limitation...)
Each thread pointing to a specific global memory area (with the coalescence and stuff, but you get the idea...)

My problem is, How do I know which thread is currenctly being run (in the kernel code) to point to the right memory area ?
I did find the cl_arm_get_core_id extension but this only gives me the workgroup, not the acutal thread being used, plus this does not seem to be available on all GPUs, since it's an extension.

I have the option to have **work_group_size = nb_compute_units / nb_cores** and have the offset to be **arm_get_core_id() * work_group_size + global_id() % work_group_size**
But maybe this group size is not optimal, and the portability issue still exists.

I can also enqueue a lot of kernels calls with global size 2880, and there I obviously know where to point to with the global Id.
But won't this lead to a lot of overhead because of the 5Million / 2880 kernel calls ? Plus any work group that finishes before the others will be idle until all workgroups for this call have finished their job.

Any ideas to do this properly are very welcome !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you are storing 1MB per WI for temporal computations (because you are not saving them, otherwise your wouldn't have memory).

Then, why not simply let it spill to global memory? Does the compiler complain? If it does complain, then you need other approaches:

---

One possibility is to create a queue (just a boolean array), of the memory zones empty for usage by the WorkGroups. And every time a new workgroup is launched it takes an empty slot and sets the boolean to "used" state. You can do this with `atomic_cmpxchg()` atomic operation.

It may introduce a small overhead to launch each WG, but it would be probably negligible if each WI is needing 1MB of global memory.

Here you have a small example of how to do `atomic_cmpxchg()` [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18950732/atomic-max-for-floats-in-opencl/18959751#18959751)